# Today got multiple ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED error even if transaction is ok

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk, runtime-error

today for the first time I got multiple ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED errors on return url on several customers transactions.

This is the specific line where the error occurs

```
$payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
```

And this is the message captured by PayPal log defined in the context configuration

```
[12-04-2019 06:14:12] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. {"name":"ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED","message":"Account can not be fetched.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

The documentation about the error is not very esplicative.

The problem is that since the transaction is successful, I don't know if refunding or bypassing this error and proceed with other operations.

As suggested here's the exception in short

```
[url:PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException:private] => https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[data:PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException:private] => {"name":"ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED","message":"Account can not be fetched.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
[message:protected] => Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 400
[file:protected] => /path/to/library/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php
[line:protected] => 177
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try {
        $payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        var_dump(json_decode($ex->getData()));
        exit(1);
    }
```

This isn't an answer yet but its a chunk of code that will help debug this and hopefully turn into an answer. Please try wrapping this around your code and post the JSON result you get, it should help debug the issue.

Comment: I integrated the answer with a short description of the exception. Thanks!